Notarization of MacOS dmg file install4j v10.0.9
We are notarizing our app (.dmg) for the first time. We updgraded install4j to version 10.0.9 to comply with the notarytool. I have valid Developer id and certificate to codesign and notarize the app. However, notarization is failing with below logs.
{
  "logFormatVersion": 1,
  "jobId": "1c59a34c-a2b3-4dc1-8980-43877411b97d",
  "status": "Invalid",
  "statusSummary": "Archive contains critical validation errors",
  "statusCode": 4000,
  "archiveFilename": "pipes_installer.dmg",
  "uploadDate": "2024-11-13T18:05:08.938Z",
  "sha256": "11c2189082f0a0785f186065358483e92babcc45668fa735d529a6dd190a1be7",
  "ticketContents": null,
  "issues": [
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/libvlc_mac.jar/plugins/libtospdif_plugin.dylib",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087721",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/libvlc_mac.jar/plugins/libtospdif_plugin.dylib",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087733",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/libvlc_mac.jar/plugins/libddummy_plugin.dylib",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087721",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/libvlc_mac.jar/plugins/libddummy_plugin.dylib",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087733",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/libvlc_mac.jar/plugins/libtaglib_plugin.dylib",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087721",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/libvlc_mac.jar/plugins/libtaglib_plugin.dylib",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087733",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/libvlc_mac.jar/plugins/liblibass_plugin.dylib",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087721",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/libvlc_mac.jar/plugins/liblibass_plugin.dylib",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087733",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    }, .........
.
.
.
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/native-sso.jar/sso/mac.zip/Contents/MacOS/nppipes",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087721",
      "architecture": "i386"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/native-sso.jar/sso/mac.zip/Contents/MacOS/nppipes",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087733",
      "architecture": "i386"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/native-sso.jar/sso/mac.zip/Contents/MacOS/nppipes",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087721",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/native-sso.jar/sso/mac.zip/Contents/MacOS/nppipes",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087733",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/jna-5.7.0.jar/com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087721",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/jna-5.7.0.jar/com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087733",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/jna-5.7.0.jar/com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib",
      "message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087721",
      "architecture": "arm64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "pipes_installer.dmg/pipes Installer.app/Contents/Resources/app/0.dat/updates.zip/jars/jna-5.7.0.jar/com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087733",
      "architecture": "arm64"
    }
  ]
}

I have looked at Signing and notarizing install4j macOs dmg. But that did not resolve my issue.
enter image description here

You have various JAR files containing binaries that are not signed automatically by install4j.
On the General Settings->Code Signing step, edit the "JAR files to be scanned for binaries" setting and add the entries
libvlc_mac*
native-sso*
jna-*

Then it should work.
